# ServiceActivator or StreamListener usages

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Is there any specification that recommending when to use `@StreamListener` `@ServiceActivator`.

Do we need to stick to `@ServiceActivator` for internal channels and `@StreamListener` for external channels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are interchangeable for majority of the use cases. `StreamListener` was primarily designed as an native alternative and also fro those who may not be familiar with Spring Integration framework.
However, as additional feature `StreamListener` supports `condition` which is not supported by the SA.